# mysql query help for delete entries from table

Tags: mysql

i have 2 msql tables (records and players) whitch contains the following fields:

```
records = Id  PlayerId  Score  Date  Checkpoints  

players = Id Login Game NickName Nation UpdatedAt Wins TimePlayed TeamName
```

i deleted few entrys from player db, and i will remove this value from records table.

the Id value is same in both db.

i used this command:

```
DELETE FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`Id` = 27;
```

but after deleted the Id` = 27 still exist in records table.

So now dont have id 27 in players table but i will remove it from records.
and i have 120 more entryes :(

Comment: If `SSH/Command Prompt/Terminal` is not helping.You should use **phpmyadmin** :D

Comment: If you dont understand what you are doing, its best to start by reading a book, doing a tutorial or 3

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai What on earth has CLI got to do with anything in this question

Comment: phpmyadmin is ok. but me need a query how can i delete entryes order by id from records, if the id does not exist in players db?

Comment: so need remove all entryes from records witch not exist by ID in players db (because deleted)

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Sorry my bad...! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM records WHERE NOT PlayerId IN (SELECT Id FROM players)
```

This would delete all records that doesn't belong to players.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT Id IN (SELECT Id FROM players)' at line 1

Comment: can i have one more question? Can you give me a query whitch can delete at once from records and players table if UpdatedAt more than 30 days old? or its enough if it can delete the records from players table then i can run the query what i got from you :)

Comment: @Joe What is the type of UpdatedAt column? Is it integer or datetime?

Comment: UpdatedAt datetime

Comment: `DELETE FROM players WHERE UpdatedAt < DATE_ADD(UpdatedAt, INTERVAL -30 DAY); DELETE FROM records WHERE NOT PlayerId IN (SELECT Id FROM players);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want related rows to be deleted automatically from the `records` table when you delete from `players`, you need to declare `PlayerId` as a foreign key with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

```
ALTER TABLE records ADD CONSTRAINT fk_playerid FOREIGN KEY (PlayerId) REFERENCES players (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This will only work if you're using InnoDB; foreign keys are ignored in MyISAM.

If you can't use a foreign key, you can join the tables when deleting:

```
DELETE p, r FROM players AS p
LEFT JOIN records AS r ON p.id = r.PlayerId
WHERE p.id = 27;
```

This needs to use `LEFT JOIN`; if you use `INNER JOIN`, it won't delete players that have no related records.

Comment: can delete all p.id at once whitch does not exist in players table?

Comment: `DELETE FROM records WHERE PlayerID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM players)`

Comment: It's practically the same as the English sentence you just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the Inner join

```
DELETE records, players  FROM records  INNER JOIN players  
WHERE records.Id= players.Id and records.Id = '27'
```

this should delete form both the tables

this if you the record doesnt exist in one table :

```
 DELETE records, players  FROM records  INNER JOIN players  
 WHERE records.Id != players.Id
```

Comment: looks like good, but i have 120 deleted records :) can query the delete for no id exist in players table?

Comment: What do you mean by 120 deleted records? Do you mean you still have 120 records to delete ?

Comment: check my Edited answer.Did you get it ?

Comment: this deleted all records now, not just whitch needed for delete :(

Comment: this should only delete the ids that are not identical.